# Excel - Filtering text columns based on their number values [Possible?]

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible to add number values to texts in excel so I can filter them based on their number values?

Example Excel Table:

[image: example chart]

So I want to filter them by their Job Levels. To do this, each level should have a value. Like: Assistant=1 Senior=2 Executive=3. Then I'll just click on the filter on "Job Level" tab and filter them by their levels.

I hope my point is clear here. Is it possible? If so, can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a helper column to show the number of Job Level.

Use the formula `=IF(B2="Assistant",1,IF(B2="Senior",2,IF(B2="Executive",3,"")))` to fill the corresponding numbers in this column.

[image]

Comment: This one is a nice trick and I'll move with it until I find what I am exactly looking for. But let's say I don't want this info to be visible for the readers.